# How to enable incoming message broadcast just for which contacts saved in mobile?

Tags: android

I want to enable broadcast for incoming messages just for which contacts are saved in my mobile. I retrieved all contacts number using this code.

```
// Search Number from phone book
    public String getContactsPhoneNumber(Context context, String originatingAddress) {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(originatingAddress));
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER}, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }

        String phoneNumber = null;

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER));
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return phoneNumber;
    }
```

The BroadcastReciever class is:

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static String messageString = "";
    Blocklist blocklist = new Blocklist();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, IncomingSms.class);

        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        boolean checks = false;

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault(); // get object and subscription id of SmsManager
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); //get data from incoming Broadcast
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus"); //get pdus messages from bundle, cast it to an Object[]
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]); //create message from pdu object

                    // get message contents from incoming message
                    String originatingAddress = currentMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                    String messageBody = currentMessage.getMessageBody();
                    long timestampMillis = currentMessage.getTimestampMillis();
                    Log.i("SmsReceive", "Sender number: " + originatingAddress + ";message: " + messageBody + " time" + String.valueOf(timestampMillis)); // log all result
```

Kindly tell me how to do this.

**Note: Permission granted on AndroidManifest file for broadcast.**

Comment: What do you mean by "enabling" broadcast  for incoming messages? Are you trying to "silently" ignore incoming SMS messages coming from numbers that are not stored on your mobile - OR do you just want to perform some operations if the sending number is unknown?

Comment: You can't filter broadcasts by phone number, so you'll have to determine what you want to do in the Receiver. Call your `getContactsPhoneNumber()` method with the `originatingAddress` you're getting in the Receiver. If it returns `null`, they're not in your Contacts. Also, you may want to do your query in an `IntentService`, instead of in the Receiver itself.

Comment: Yes , i want to perform some operations if the sending number is unknown

Comment: thanks i got it. @MikeM.

Comment: On receiving sms IncomingSMS class gives java.lang.NullPointerException. please tell me why this happened? @MikeM.

Comment: There's no way I can determine that without knowing what's throwing the `Exception`.